# Javascript variables in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

My knowledge of javascript is medium, sorry if this question seem too newbie

I call a (stripe) script to display the checkout, my 'desc' variable, which is properly in my page, is just not used in the  tag. Instead I have 'desc'.

data-description='bonjour' **works**

var desc = 'bonjour'
data-description=desc **does not work**

what am I missing here ?

```
<script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key=""
      data-amount=amount
      data-name="<%= current_user.full_name %>"
      data-description=desc
      data-panel-label="Encaisser"
      data-label="Payer par carte"
      data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
      data-locale="fr"
      data-currency="eur">
    </script>
```

Comment: is amount, desc a variable or reference in your server side platform?

Comment: `<script no javascript here>only here</script>`

Comment: no, it's local page variable. It seems the variables in <script) tag are not used. if I put data-description = 'hello' it works, but var grettings = 'hello' and data-description = grettings it doesn't :-(

Comment: <script no javascript here>only here</script> I see, is their a way with getElementById or something like it ? I will look for it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have any Javascript there - what you have is only HTML markup, describing a `script` tag and its *HTML attributes*, so you can't use `var` or anything else particular to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script no javascript here because this is HTML, not JS>
  JS can only be used here, in the content of the script tag
</script>
```